Ghidra find xref function chain
Is there a Ghidra feature that lets me see the "chain" of xrefs? Like, potential call stacks? Or the chain of function xref? This feels like something that should be doable given what I've seen of Ghidra so far.
How I'm imagining it would work is it would look at the xref of a function, then any of those that are in another function, it'd go to the top of that function and repeat from that address.
Specifically I'm looking for a function and I've identified two different higher level functions that probably use that function at some point inside of them. As I'm going through the functions, I'd like a way to check if at any point the "call stack" contains a method I have already worked with before.
Is something like this possible? Or is there a tutorial for a scripting system I could use to do something myself?

Go to Window > Function Call Graph
and you get a nice interactive graph of function calls

If you do Window > Function Call Tree
you get a simpler list view as well

